# How to pass variables down to partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am New to Ruby on rails, I am using Rails 4.1.9, Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows xp

This is my models

```
class Migproject < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true 
        validates :clientname, presence: true
        validates :startdate, presence: true
        #validates :enddate, presence: true
        validates :is_active, presence: true
        validates :statusid, presence: true

        has_many :projectmembers, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :projectmembers, :allow_destroy => true
    end

    class Projectmember < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :fk_userid, presence: true
        validates :fk_roleid, presence: true

        belongs_to :roles
        belongs_to :users
        belongs_to :migproject  
    end
```

This is my view

```
<%= mp.fields_for :projectmembers do |pm| %>
        <%= render "projectmember_fields", :projectmembers => pm %>
      <% end %>
```

this is my partial

```
<tr class="fields">
  <td>Select Users :</td><td><%= projectmembers.collection_select :fk_userid, User.all, :pk_userid, :fname, {:prompt => true} %></td>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Role :</td><td><%= projectmembers.collection_select :fk_roleid, Role.all, :pk_roleid, :rolename, {:prompt => true} %></td>
  <td><span class="removefld"><%= projectmembers.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to "Remove" %></span></td>
</tr>
```

But when i run i get error like this

```
undefined local variable or method `projectmembers' for #<#<Class:0x4e13680>:0x2ea41e0>
```

Where am i making mistake?

Is there any other method to add a dynamic field to a form?

---

This is my application helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
def link_to_add_fields(name, mp, association)
        new_object = mp.object.send(association).klass.new
        id = new_object.object_id
        fields = mp.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |build|
            render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", mp: build)
        end
        link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","")})
    end 
end
```

Can i render a block of HTML from same page instead of calling partial in helper?

Answer (score 6):

You need to write it like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "projectmember_fields", :locals => {:projectmembers => pm} %>
```

More info in the chapter "3.4.4 Passing Local Variables" of the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

---

**EDIT**: Just understood. I had this before. You issue comes from the `link_to_add_fields` method, at the following line:

```
render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", mp: build)
```

This `render` call also need to the local variables, like this:

```
render(:partial => "#{association.to_s.singularize}_fields", :locals => {:projectmembers => build}
```

Next time, find a way to display the whole backtrace of your error, and see each invoked line of your code.

Comment: Perhaps due to the aliasing of `render` to `render_with_haml`

Comment: But still it doesnt works for me.

This is the complete error message it shows


NameError in Migprojects#show

Showing C:/Sites/vinpa/app/views/migprojects/_projectmember_fields.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined local variable or method `projectmembers' for #<#<Class:0x5220f90>:0x395bab8>

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the model name for the form builder

`<%= render "projectmember_fields", pm_form: pm %>`

and inside the partial:

`<%= pm_form.collection_select ..`

Comment: Still i get the same error. these are the trace
app/views/migprojects/_projectmember_fields.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_migprojects__projectmember_fields_html_erb___866008266_25255512'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `block in link_to_add_fields'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:5:in `link_to_add_fields'
app/views/migprojects/new.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_migprojects_new_html_erb___572287492_43497120'
app/views/migprojects/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_migprojects_new_html_erb___572287492_43497120'
I can add dummy content in partial, but get erroe with form element i am not

Comment: where do you have the link_to_add ?
When I need to build nested form I usually use this gem:

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

that builds the method for you.

could the link_to_add be the problem?

Comment: I have that in application helper


module ApplicationHelper
def link_to_add_fields(name, mp, association)
        new_object = mp.object.send(association).klass.new
        id = new_object.object_id
        fields = mp.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |build|
            render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", mp: build)
        end
        link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n","")})
    end 
end

Comment: change in your helper:

`render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", mp: build)` to `render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", projectmembers: build)`

Comment: As per your earlier comment, the problem is with `<td class="addfld"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add", mp, :projectmembers %>` when i remove this from page i dont get the errors.  But i am not sure how to fix this..